# regEx pattern for blocking special characters fully, and blocking spaces start and end of the sting and allow in between words in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, regex-group

regEx pattern for blocking special characters fully, and blocking spaces start and end of the sting and allow in between words in JavaScript,

I have tried in many ways but i couldn't get it.

requirement : should not have space before and after the string and should not have special characters(`<>?/|\:"*+`).

I have tried this `^[^<>?/+:"|\\\\*+\\s][^<>?+:"|\\\\*+]*$`

this is handling everything except space after string

Comment: Could you provide examples of strings you are trying to match and strings you are trying not to match? It's easier to provide an accurate regex with more information.

Comment: sample string:

"t"  - valid
" test"  - invalid
"test "  - invalid
"test         test"  - valid
"test<"  - invalid
"test< test"  - Invalid

Comment: basically i don't want allow space start and end of the string it can be allowed between words, And  should not allow any of these <, >, ?, /, :, ", \, |, +, * special characters .

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to nail down, and normally I'd just split this into two checks (one for special characters and another for leading & trailing whitespace), or simply trim leading and trailing whitespace and just test for special characters.

```
/^(?!\s)[^<>?/|\\:"*+]*[^<>?/|\\:"*+\s]$/
```

- `^(?!\s)` doesn't start with non-whitespace character
- `[^<>?/|\\:"*+\s]$` non-special/ends with non-whitespace character
- `[^<>?/|\\:"*+]*` doesn't contain any special characters

Test Suite

```
const regex = /^(?!\s)[^<>?/|\\:"*+]*[^<>?/|\\:"*+\s]$/;

it.each([
  // valid - single word
  ["t", true],
  ["te", true],
  ["tes", true],
  ["test", true],
  // valid - multi-word
  ["test test", true],
  ["test test test", true],
  [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel vulputate lacus, bibendum auctor nulla. Cras eget vehicula arcu. Aliquam non lacus sed quam consequat laoreet sed at massa. Nam magna nulla, tempus id consequat efficitur, luctus non sapien. Maecenas eget volutpat neque. Etiam lobortis ipsum a imperdiet semper. Sed vel quam porta, lobortis metus commodo, aliquam libero. Vestibulum nulla tellus, sagittis quis auctor id, malesuada ac purus. Phasellus nunc mi, viverra id sem ut, laoreet porta orci. Cras malesuada quam ut auctor tristique. Suspendisse bibendum purus tortor, nec finibus magna imperdiet ut. Mauris id ligula dictum, feugiat nulla non, bibendum nunc. Phasellus eget sem cursus, placerat risus non, vehicula quam.",
    true
  ],
  // invalid - leading/trailing whitespace
  ["", false],
  ["  test", false],
  ["test  ", false],
  ["  test  ", false],
  ["  test test  ", false],
  // invalid - special chars only
  ["<", false],
  [">", false],
  ["?", false],
  ["/", false],
  ["|", false],
  ["\\", false],
  [":", false],
  ['"', false],
  ["*", false],
  ["+", false],
  // invalid - starts with special chars
  ["<t", false],
  ["<te", false],
  ["<tes", false],
  ["<test", false],
  [">test", false],
  ["?test", false],
  ["/test", false],
  ["|test", false],
  ["\\test", false],
  [":test", false],
  ['"test', false],
  ["*test", false],
  ["+test", false],
  // invalid - ends with special chars
  ["t<", false],
  ["st<", false],
  ["est<", false],
  ["test<", false],
  ["test>", false],
  ["test?", false],
  ["test/", false],
  ["test|", false],
  ["test\\", false],
  ["test:", false],
  ['test"', false],
  ["test*", false],
  ["test+", false],
  // invalid - special chars mixed
  ["te<st", false],
  ["te>st", false],
  ["te?st", false],
  ["te/st", false],
  ["te|st", false],
  ["te\\st", false],
  ["te:st", false],
  ['te"st', false],
  ["te*st", false],
  ["te+st", false],
  // invalid - leading/trailing and special chars mixed
  ["  te<st", false],
  ["te<st  ", false],
  ["  te<st  ", false],
  // invalid - multi-word, leading/trailing whitespace, and special chars
  ["te?st test", false],
  ["test te?st", false],
  ["test ? test", false],
  ["  te?st test", false],
  ["test te?st  ", false],
  ["  test ? test  ", false]
])("should validate [%s] - %s", (input, expected) => {
  expect(regex.test(input)).toEqual(expected);
});
```

[image: Edit regex - no special chars and leading/trailing whitespace, allow words]

Comment: Thanks for the help.I tried your code which working if string length more than 2.
ex :  ["te", true] test suit got failed. received false , expected true.

Comment: basically i don't want allow space start and end of the string it can be allowed between words, And should not allow any of these <, >, ?, /, :, ", \, |, +, * special characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `^(?!\s)[^<>/:"\\|+*\n]*[^<>/:"\\|+*\s]$`

It matches all the test patterns you gave. There's just a bit of duplication in character classes but that's because at the very end we need to make sure it doesn't end with a whitespace character.

There's an explanation of the pattern pieces in the regex101 link.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hVlv2D/2)